# How do I add a hyperlinks to image using VBA?

Tags: image, vba, hyperlink, addition

I have a script that will run on GPO on Windows Server 2012.

It's pretty simple stuff, but I cannot fathom how to add a hyperlink around an image! I have:

`objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture "linktoimage.html"`

This works a dream, I can see the image and there is no issue. But how do I add a hyperlink to this image so that when folks click on it they are taken to my desired hyperlink location. I know adding an image is simply a line of code, hoping for same for adding a hyperlink.

I am not doing this in excel or anything of the kind, just Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is about Word, you need to save a reference the shape you just created and then use that reference as an argument to Document.Hyperlinks.Add

```
Option Explicit

Sub LinkImageTest()
    Dim oSelection As Selection
    Dim oDocument As Document
    Dim oShape As InlineShape

    Set oSelection = Application.Selection
    Set oDocument = oSelection.Document

    Set oShape = oSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Pde_zs2tuj0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/iBq9KSwTTLk/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg")

    oDocument.Hyperlinks.Add oShape, "http://www.microsoft.com"

End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers! That was useful. Set it as oShape and applied link like you did here.